# Detecting whether an image has been Photoshopped

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for a program that can detect whether an image has been Photoshopped (or modified with some other program). Any OS is fine, I am mostly looking for a program with a high accuracy. Free is better.

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10899/a-program-that-diffs-2-images